# MySQL server load optimization

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

Let's say we have 2 db tables. 
First table "laptops"

id         |        name

---

1                  apple

2 sony
...

and second table "colors"

id         |        color

---

1  white

2                  black

2 red

2 blue

...

If I want to get some html table like

Laptop  |  Available colors

Apple      1 (white)

Sony       3 (red, blue, black)

...

I need to create "while" and query every time for every laptop. It will load server if there are more than 10 000 laptops for example. Is there any optimised way to get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `SQL JOIN`. However you need to have a table which links both tables together.

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM laptops t 
    LEFT JOIN colors c ON t.id=c.id
```

e.g. if you want to Count colors you could do something like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, COUNT(c.id) AS numberofcolors FROM laptops t 
    LEFT JOIN colors c ON t.id=c.id
    GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: Either you use the `Count` method or an equivalent method in sql. You need to use `GroupBy` as well.

Comment: what does mean c. and t.? please explain

Comment: c and t are aliases for the tables. "laptops t" t is an alias for laptops so `laptops.id = t.id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you also need to output color names you have to use GROUP_CONCAT